# Is there a way to call ruby1.9 without loading rubygems?

Tags: ruby, shell, rubygems, ruby-1.9

So ruby 1.9 is really nice in that it'll automatically require rubygems, and hence when you call `require 'somegem'` without first requiring rubygems it'll work, and that's generally awesome.

But I have a ton of shell scripts using ruby, and they generally don't rely on rubygems. Shell tools should run instantly, and loading rubygems for nothing is a major drag, mostly because it involves a bunch of disk operations with scattered small files.

I want to be able to tell ruby, when running these shell scripts, to skip loading gems. Ideally, something like `#!ruby --no-rubygems` in the shebang line.

Is there such a thing? Or maybe a compile option that'll tell ruby rubygems must be required manually?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can use the `--disable-gems` option.

Note that whether or not passing options in the shebang line works depends on your operating system. Some operating systems don't support passing options *at all*, some only support passing *one* option or argument.

So, if you have for example

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
```

Then it's pretty unlikely that you will be able to attach the option to the end. If OTOH you change that to

```
#!/usr/local/bin/ruby --disable-gems
```

Then you have hardwired the location of the Ruby binary into your script.

And of course there are operating systems that don't interpret shebang lines *at all*. (After all, they were never specified in any standard, and aren't even properly documented.)

An alternative would be to set the `RUBYOPT` environment variable in your shell environment and simply switch to a different environment with `RUBYOPT` unset (or set to `-w`, my personal favorite) for your Ruby development.